# C# list installed certificates

Tags: c#, certificate

first i'm an complete newby on c#, so im just searching on the web  for posibilities
What i want to get: I want a button which retrieves a list of installed certificates in the personal store.

i tried already a little, but get messages about missing references etc. So i hope someone can give me a litte advice how to achieve this.

what i found on the web is:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
        public static X509Certificate2 selectCert(StoreName store, StoreLocation location, string windowTitle, string windowMsg)
    {

        X509Certificate2 certSelected = null;
        X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(store, location);
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        X509Certificate2Collection col = x509Store.Certificates;
        X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(col, windowTitle, windowMsg, X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

        if (sel.Count > 0)
        {
            X509Certificate2Enumerator en = sel.GetEnumerator();
            en.MoveNext();
            certSelected = en.Current;
        }

        x509Store.Close();

        return certSelected;
    }
```

yours

(i use visual studio...)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a reference to `System.Security.dll` to use the [X509Certificate2UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui?view=netframework-4.8) class.
2. you can use foreach

```cs
if (sel.Count > 0){
  foreach(var cert in sel){
    certSelected = cert ;
  }
}
```

2. you can make it even shorte when using linq

```cs
using System.Linq;
...

if (sel.Count > 0){
  return sel.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `if` condition in 2nd example. Just fire `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Correct. I just used it to reference the existing code.